# Do the fourier components of a periodic function need to satisfy the boundary conditions imposed on it?

Tags: mathematical-physics, solid-state-physics

I cannot understand the opening statement of the second derivation of Bloch's theorem in the solid state physics book by Ashcroft and Mermin (Chapter 8, eqn 8.30).

> We start with the observation that one can always expand any function obeying the Born-von Karman boundary condition (8.22) in the set of all plane waves that satisfy the bondary condition ...

The equation 8.22 is $$\psi(\mathbf{r} + N_i \mathbf{a}_i) = \psi(\mathbf{r}) $$ where $N_i$ are the number of lattice points in the crystal in the three directions and $\mathbf{a}_i$ are the primitive vectors.

So the plane waves are the fourier components of the wave functions. What I don't understand is why the fourier components(plane waves) have to satisfy the boundary condition that is imposed on the wave function. More generally, if the function satisfies a boundary condition, do its fourier components have to do that as well? And if not then why is this condition imposed here?

Comment: I'm not ready to *prove* it, but my guess is that because the basis functions are orthogonal, you can't construct a sum that satisfies the condition without each individual term satisfying it.

Comment: Consider the inverse - under what conditions could the Fourier components of a solution _not_ meet the boundary conditions?

Comment: Suppose all even terms deviate from the boundary value by a fixed amount and all odd terms vary by the same magnitude but negative value